# Where is Microsoft .Net built-in dependency injection library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection

I am using .NET 4.5.2 with Visual Studio 2015. I need a built-in Microsoft dependency injection library. I tried adding `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` reference but I am not able to find it. I checked `framework` and `extensions` in the assembly when adding a reference. Is there a way to get any built-in dependency injection framework for wpf? I am not allowed to use any external libraries without a lengthy approval process.

Comment: I think your looking for [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) and here some quick start [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Unity is rarely used anymore, it's typically better to use the standard `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: ahh, didnt know there was support for that in .net 4.5, good to know thanks @JSteward

Comment: @JSteward actually, I got an error. `Cannot resolve dependency to assembly netstandard`. I researched it and found out I need .net core. Unfortunetly, .net core in my organization is not approved.

Comment: @Luke101 if you look at the nuget dependencies you will see that it works with .NETFramework 4.6.1 platform as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) works if you are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later.

If you're still on .NET Framework 4.5.2 and want to use Unity, you should use the [Unity.Container](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Container/) package.

You install a package into your project using [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio).

Comment: Did you manage to use dependency injection in .NET 4.6.1? I followed the Tutorial: Use dependency injection in .NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage) but I get the compiler error:
Program.cs(87,33,87,37): error CS0103: The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context